# Better way to iterate over dataset and change a feature value for other value in a future index in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataset of velocities registered by sensors on highways and I'm changing the `label` values for the `avg5` (velocities average of 5 minutes timestamp) 2 hours in the future (the normal is 30 minutes. The `label` value of now is the observed `avg5` of 30 minutes in the future).

My dataset have the following features and values:
[image: head of the dataset: features and values]

[image: expanded dataset]

And I'm doing this switch of values by this way:

```py
hours_added = datetime.timedelta(hours = 2)

for index in data_copy.index:

  hours_ahead = data.loc[index, "timestamp5"] + hours_added
  result = data_copy[((data_copy["timestamp5"] == hours_ahead) & (data_copy["sensor_id"] == data_copy["sensor_id"].loc[index]))]

  if len(result) == 1:
    data_copy.at[index, "label"] = result["avg5"]

  if(index % 50 == 0):
    print(f"Index: {index}")
```

The code is querying 2 hours ahead and catching the result for the same sensor_id that I'm iterating now. I only change the value of my label if the result brings me something (`len(result) == 1)`.

My dataframe has 2950521 indexes and at the moment I'm publishing this question the kernel is running for more then 24 hours and only reached the 371650 Index.

So I started thinking that I'm doing something wrong or if have a better way of change these values who don't take so long time.

**For reproducing purposes**
The desired behavior is to assign the `avg5` of the respective sensor_id of 2 hours in the future for the label 2 hours before.
For reproducibility, take as example a sample of my dataset with the 10 first registers:

```py
{'sensor_id': {0: 1385001,
  1: 1385001,
  2: 1385001,
  3: 1385001,
  4: 1385001,
  5: 1385001,
  6: 1385001,
  7: 1385001,
  8: 1385001,
  9: 1385001},
 'label': {0: 50.79999923706055,
  1: 52.69230651855469,
  2: 50.0,
  3: 48.61538314819336,
  4: 48.0,
  5: 47.90909194946289,
  6: 51.41666793823242,
  7: 48.3684196472168,
  8: 49.8636360168457,
  9: 48.66666793823242},
 'avg5': {0: 49.484848,
  1: 51.735294,
  2: 51.59375,
  3: 49.266666,
  4: 50.135135999999996,
  5: 50.5,
  6: 50.8,
  7: 52.69230699999999,
  8: 50.0,
  9: 48.615383},
 'timestamp5': {0: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:05:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:10:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:15:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:20:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:25:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:30:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:35:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:40:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:45:00')}}
```

Let's suppose I want to assign to the first `label` (where the timestamp is 2014-08-01 00:00:00) the value of the `avg5` field of 40 minutes ahead (2014-08-01 00:40:00) for the same `sensor_id` (in this example all the sensors are the same, but I have a lot of more others registered at the dataset), so my `label` of the index 0 (50.79) should receive the value of the `avg5` of index 8 (50.0) if the `sensor_id` are the same.

Comment: I am convinced that I can speed this up by 1000%. Can you put an example data frame and a expected output that I make it easy to copy and paste?

Comment: I am confused by `data_copy["sensor_id"] == data_copy["sensor_id"].loc[index]` - What does this do?

Comment: @pecey sorry, I forgot to mention and I'll add to the question: I can only change the value of labels for the same sensor_id. So I'm querying 2 hours in the future for and checking if the sensor_id is the same for then change the value

Comment: So basically for every sensor, you are checking if you have a value exactly 2 hours (7200 s) from now, and then replacing the current value with that? What happens if you have data 7201 seconds from now? Are you allowed to switch or do you need exactly 7200 seconds difference?

Comment: @ansev I updated the question with one example.

Comment: @pecey exactly. I'm doing this way because my label right now is so closer to the avg5 since my label is the value of avg5 30 minutes in future. When I'm training the model is getting avg5 as the only and most important feature. So this is an experiment to my model don't have this behavior.

Comment: I guess one way to go about this would be to create a smaller dataframe with the sensor id, avg5 and timestamp. Add 2 hours to all the timestamp values. Index both the dataframes of the respective timestamp values. And then perform a join between the two dataframes.  This should be much faster than iterating over each row.

Comment: Can you update your question to include code/data that can be copy pasted into an interpreter? I can't copy-paste text in images.

Comment: @cs95 I can't share the dataset, since it is a 17GB dataset.

Comment: @IsacMoura: The actual dataset is not that interesting here, you can create a small example dataset that demonstrates the problem (e.g., 3-4 columns, 10-20 rows).

Comment: Not sure because i cannot replicate your code but maybe using a dictionary with {date: avg5} could be much faster (assigning to df['label'] = dictionary[time+2h])

Comment: You can use df.avg5.apply(func) . func will take a date and do the modifications.You can also load dataframe in chunks to relax your cpu. Also use "dask" for this big purpose.

Comment: You've added a bounty but failed to add in any input or output data, if you just followed simple instructions found in [ask] and [mcve] this question would have been answered most likely within the hour you asked it. Please add a sample of your data, just print `df.head(15).to_dict()` and paste it in your code and create a sample of expected values from those 15 lines and paste that too.

Comment: @Datanovice I strongly disagree, once this is a question about good practices I can't see where sharing data is important for answering this. The real problem is the demanding time for iterating over a big dataset. But if you think this will help you, so ok.

Comment: you have about 4 people, several with reps higher than 20k asking you for reproducable sample, I'm not sure why you think this question is the exception?

Comment: As I said before I didn't know a way to share my dataset with them, but I'll follow your suggestion and add a sample.

Comment: Please, check again the question and tell me if it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of how your code works, it seems that it is taking so long because it is running in something like O(n^c) time. What I mean by that is that for *each index*, it has to go over the entire dataset multiple times to check the conditions.

Therefore, it would be optimal to try and avoid going over the entire dataset for each index - i.e., make it work in O(n) linear time. To achieve that, I'd do the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import datetime

data_copy = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'sensor_id': {
        0: 1385001, 1: 1385001, 2: 1385001, 3: 1385001, 4: 1385001, 5: 1385001,
        6: 1385001, 7: 1385001, 8: 1385001, 9: 1385001},
    'label': {
        0: 50.79999923706055, 1: 52.69230651855469, 2: 50.0, 3: 48.61538314819336,
        4: 48.0, 5: 47.90909194946289, 6: 51.41666793823242, 7: 48.3684196472168,
        8: 49.8636360168457, 9: 48.66666793823242},
    'avg5': {
        0: 49.484848, 1: 51.735294, 2: 51.59375, 3: 49.266666,
        4: 50.135135999999996, 5: 50.5, 6: 50.8, 7: 52.69230699999999,
        8: 50.0, 9: 48.615383},
    'timestamp5': {
        0: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:05:00'),
        2: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:10:00'), 3: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:15:00'),
        4: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:20:00'), 5: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:25:00'),
        6: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:30:00'), 7: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:35:00'),
        8: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:40:00'), 9: Timestamp('2014-08-01 00:45:00')}})
hours_added = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 40)

# Create a data series that combines the information about sensor_id & timestamp5
sen_time = data_copy['sensor_id'].astype(str) + data_copy['timestamp5'].astype(str)
# Create a dictionary of the corresponding { sensor_id + timestamp5 : avg5 } values
dictionary = pd.Series(data_copy['avg5'].values, sen_time).to_dict()
# Create a data series combining the timestamp5 + 40 mins information
timePlus40 = data_copy['timestamp5'] + hours_added
# Create a mapping column that combines the sensor_id & timestamp5+40mins
sensor_timePlus40 = (data_copy['sensor_id'].astype(str) + timePlus40.astype(str))
# Create a new_label series by mapping the dictionary onto sensor_timePlus40
new_label = sensor_timePlus40.map(dictionary)
# Extract indices where this series has non-NaN values
where = new_label.notnull()
# Replace the values in the 'label' column with only non-NaN new_label values
data_copy.loc[where, 'label'] = new_label.loc[where]
```

I believe this is a similar idea to what @pecey and @iracebeth_18 suggested in the comments.

This **EDIT**ed version reflects the OP's desire (from the comments) to update the `label` column with only non-NaN values.

The result looks like this:

```
> print(data_copy)

   sensor_id      label       avg5          timestamp5
0    1385001  50.000000  49.484848 2014-08-01 00:00:00
1    1385001  48.615383  51.735294 2014-08-01 00:05:00
2    1385001  50.000000  51.593750 2014-08-01 00:10:00
3    1385001  48.615383  49.266666 2014-08-01 00:15:00
4    1385001  48.000000  50.135136 2014-08-01 00:20:00
5    1385001  47.909092  50.500000 2014-08-01 00:25:00
6    1385001  51.416668  50.800000 2014-08-01 00:30:00
7    1385001  48.368420  52.692307 2014-08-01 00:35:00
8    1385001  49.863636  50.000000 2014-08-01 00:40:00
9    1385001  48.666668  48.615383 2014-08-01 00:45:00
```

Comparing the speed of this code to yours with `timeit` yields faster running time and the diffrence should only increase the larger the dataset gets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll search a way to avoid NaN values but your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: What would you prefer instead of NaNs? None, 0, or just keeping the previously existing value in the ‘label’ column?

Comment: The previous value, since 0 or NaN could affect my model performance. I think this could be done with `replace()`

Comment: I believe that the `pandas.DataFrame.replace()` function is meant to do something else. I have updated my answer based on your feedback. Also note that I changed the code so that new columns are not being added to the `data_copy` dataframe, because I think that constantly working with the entire large dataframe could unnecessarily slow down the process. Instead, I am creating separate `pandas.Series()` objects (similar to one dataframe column)  for the mapping etc. that are separate from the main dataframe. Hopefully that will help speed things up even more!